# MMS is assigning same alias to two data nodes of different shards and replicasets

Tags: mongodb-mms

I am using MMS to monitor a 13 node MongoDB Cluster(3 Config Servers, 4 MongoS, 2 replica sets with 2 members + 1 arbiter each). MMS was working properly since its installation, but now it is not monitoring the shards & replica-sets properly.

It is monitoring only 4 nodes(1 Primary 1 Secondary and 2 arbiters) out of 6 nodes and auto-removing the other replica-set(primary + secondary) every time I am adding them manually.
Also for the replica-set it is monitoring it is taking the primary secondary and arbiter as independent nodes(even though it is showing correct TYPE for them in the monitoring window).

When I checked Host Mapping it was surprised to see that it was showing the same alias name for both the Primary nodes and same for both the secondaries. I guess this is the reason it is not showing those 2 nodes in the monitoring window.

I manually removed those entries of same alias names from the Host Mapping window but it is auto-updating it after few minutes.

Why is it considering the two different nodes as same and taking the same alias name for them ? Is it a bug ?

MMS is working well for Config-servers and MongoS nodes.

My MMS group is **"MMS@Ork"**

My Data nodes are as follows:

Server1 -> Primary of Replica-set1 + Secondary of Replica-set2(2 Nodes)
Server2 -> Primary of Replica-set2 + Secondary of Replica-set1(2 Nodes)
Arbiters of both replica-sets are on separate machines.
I have kept one port number common for both the primaries and other port number common for both the secondaries.

Comment: Version of all the nodes in the cluster is 2.4.9 and that of MMS monitoring-agent is 2.3.1

Comment: This is a question about administrating MongoDB, not about programming for it. This means the question is much more appropriate for https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated the question for migration.